# How can I learn Civilization?

Tags: civilization-5

A few years ago I downloaded Civilization but for the life of me I couldn't understand how to play it. And I had played and mastered games like Cezar and Starcraft before.

Anyway I can learn and get some background about the game before and/or while playing it?

Comment: Play on the easiest difficulty.  I'm pretty sure it comes with a tutorial.

Comment: Definitely agree with @fbueckert - play on the easiest setting, if I remember correctly there's a tutorial.

Comment: Ohhh thanks for closing, i had a huge answer of 5000+ words almost ready to post.... I do not think this is a duplicate question. I do think this damn grumpy stack community closes questions to quick and try to play bosses over everyone.

Comment: Anyway, check http://www.civfanatics.com it's a very helpfull civilization community. Start a game and post updates with screenshots about it. Watch other games or even get somebody to watch your stream and get direct advice.

Comment: @MennoGouw post it into the old question.

Comment: @studoku It's not about beginner strategies. It's about how to learn civ in steps, to what you should pay attention on as a beginner, posting games on civfanatics, etc. I just have some small parts covering strategies and build orders.

Comment: try Civilopedia Android app, i did and it helps very much; play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spears.civilopedia

Answer (score 2):

The easiest ways to learn to play Civ:

1. Just jump in: Set the game on the easiest setting, set it for a small number of opponents, and play. Listen to the in game advice.
2. Find a few "Let's Play" videos on Civilization 5
3. Find a strategy guide or FAQ on the game and read it.

Civilization 5 is a 4-x wargame. This means that it is expected that you will need to: e**X**plore, e**X**pand, e**X**ploit, and then e**X**terminate! So the game is built around the phases of exploring the map, expanding (building new cities) in the better available areas of the explored map, maximizing resources worked by the cities, and waging successful war on all that are smaller than you.

If you want to take a slightly more peaceful path to victory, you will still need to build up your military (to keep the AI from deciding you are small enough to knock off), and then go for the science victory (build a rocketship to start a colony on Alpha Centauri) or a diplomat victory (be so well liked by all the AI that they vote you president of the world for life).

This should hopefully be enough info to get you started. For more specific strategies, I'd suggest consulting strategy guides.

Comment: the AI is still kinda crap when it comes to diplomacy as even if you surround their borders with an army and have enough gold that if used in the real world could pay off every country's debt (including the US) and offer 9/10's of it in exchange for peace they still wont deal (i have a million guns pointed at your head and throwing much money at you, why wont you be my friend!) so the science victory is most often the most peaceful way to win unless you get some human players in